# Como fazer a conexão de back-end e front-end?

Tags: java, front-end, servidor, tomcat

preciso de ajuda de vocês. Tenho um formulário HTML, que solicita dois tipos de dados ao usuário, a Altura e o Peso. E tenho um código em Java, que vai receber estes dois dados e calcular o IMC. A minha pergunta é como posso fazer a conexão entre o back-end e o front-end ? Já possuo o servidor Tomcat 9.0 rodando integrado no Eclipse Java EE.

Formulário HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculador de IMC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="formulario">
            <h1>Calculador de IMC</h1>
            <hr>
            <h2>Digite seu peso e altura.</h2>
            <form class="forms" method="POST" action="receber.jsp">
                Peso: <input class="caixa" name="peso">
                Altura: <input class="caixa" name="altura">
                <input class="send" type="submit" value="Enviar"> 
            </form>
        </div>  
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Cálculo IMC em Java:

```
        String peso = request.getParameter("peso");
        String altura = request.getParameter("altura");
        double peso1 = Double.parseDouble(peso);
        double altura1 = Double.parseDouble(altura);

        double imc = peso1/(altura1*altura1);
        System.out.printf(" IMC  = %.2f %n",  imc );
              
        if (imc < 18.5) {
        System.out.println("ClassificaÃ§Ã£o: Magreza");
        System.out.println("VocÃª precisa de uma dieta hipercalÃ³rica.");
        }

        if (imc >= 18.5 & imc < 25 ) {
        System.out.println("ClassificaÃ§Ã£o: Normal");
        System.out.println("VocÃª precisa de uma dieta normocalÃ³rica.");
        }

        if (imc >= 25 & imc < 30 ) {
            System.out.println("ClassificaÃ§Ã£o: Sobrepeso");
            System.out.println("VocÃª precisa de uma dieta hipocalÃ³rica.");
        }

        if (imc > 30 ) {
            System.out.println("ClassificaÃ§Ã£o: Obesidade ");
            System.out.println("VocÃª precisa de uma dieta hipocalÃ³rica.");
        }
```

Comment: Olá. Estude sobre Servlets e JSP (JavaServer Pages).

Comment: Tudo bem, já estava pesquisando em torno deste assunto, vou continuar estudando. Obrigado pelo comentário!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basicamente criando a página receber.jsp que vai receber as variáveis POST e você decide o que fazer com elas.

Eu uso php, mas jsp tbm é linguagem server side

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. +1